# C Language - Rehashing a Separate Chaining Hash Table

Tags: c, function, pointers, data-structures, hashtable

So I looked everywhere to get inspired but I didn't really find anything for rehashing a hash table using separate chaining method. So I tried myself, I think I know what I'm doing wrong, but I don't know how else to implement it, please help.

Everything works, except the new added function rehash()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct list_node
{

   struct list_node *next;
   char *key;
   char *value; 

};

struct hash_table 
{

    int table_size;
    struct list_node **list_arr;

};  




unsigned int hash(const char *key, unsigned int table_size);
struct hash_table *initialize(unsigned int table_size);
struct list_node *find(struct hash_table *H, const char *key);
void insert(struct hash_table *H, const char *key, const char *value);
void dump(struct hash_table *H);
void del(struct hash_table *H, const char *key);
struct hash_table *rehash(struct hash_table *H);

unsigned int 
hash(const char *key, unsigned int table_size)
{
    unsigned long int hashx = 0;
    for(int i=0;key[i];i++)
    {
        hashx = (hashx<<5) + key[i];
    }

    return (hashx%table_size);
}


struct hash_table
*initialize(unsigned int table_size)
{

    struct hash_table *H = malloc(sizeof(*H));
    H->list_arr = malloc(sizeof(*H->list_arr)*table_size);

    H->table_size = table_size;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<table_size; i++)
    {
        H->list_arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(*H->list_arr[i]));
        H->list_arr[i]->next = NULL;
    }

    return H;

}


void
insert(struct hash_table *H, const char *key, const char *value)
{   
    unsigned int index = hash(key, H->table_size);
    struct list_node *head = H->list_arr[index];
    struct list_node *current = head->next;
    
    
    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(current->key,key)==0)
        {
            free(current->value);
            current->value = malloc(strlen(value)+1);
            strcpy(current->value,value);
            return;
        }

        current=current->next;

    }

    struct list_node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(*H->list_arr[index]));
    newNode->next = head->next;
    head->next = newNode;
    newNode->key = malloc(strlen(key)+1);
    newNode->value = malloc(strlen(value)+1);
    strcpy(newNode->key,key);
    strcpy(newNode->value,value);


}

void
dump(struct hash_table *H)
{
    for( int i = 0; i<H->table_size; i++)
    {
        struct list_node *entry = H->list_arr[i]->next;
        if(entry==NULL){continue;}
        printf("Index[%d]: ", i);
        while(entry!=NULL)
        {
            printf("\t%s|%s\t--> ", entry->key, entry->value);
            entry = entry->next;
        }
        printf("\tNULL");
        printf("\n");

    }
}

void delete(struct hash_table *H, const char *key)
{
    unsigned int index = hash(key,H->table_size);
    struct list_node *prev = H->list_arr[index];

    while(strcmp(prev->next->key,key)!=0)
    {
        if(prev->next==NULL){printf("Key not found!");return;}
        prev=prev->next;
    }

    struct list_node *temp = prev->next;
    prev->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);

}


struct hash_table *rehash(struct hash_table *H)
{
    unsigned int old_size = H->table_size;
    struct list_node *old_entries = H->list_arr;

    H = initialize(2*old_size);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<old_size; i++)
    {
        while(old_entries[i]!=NULL)
        {
            insert(H,old_entries[i].key,old_entries[i].value);
            old_entries[i] = old_entries[i]->next;
        }
    }

    free(old_entries);

    return H;
}



int main()
{   

    struct hash_table *H = initialize(20);
    insert(H,"name1","David");
    insert(H,"name2","Radka");
    dump(H);    
    H = rehash(H);
    dump(H);
    return 1;

}
```

I think doing old_entries[i] is wrong, but nothing else comes to mind, please help me resolve this.

Comment: This is wrong on multiple levels. Yes, your `old_entries` logic is broken, if for no other reason than because the types clearly don't match up. But the real issue is the list item management. You should never need to fire insert in a rehash.  All bucket-expansion is about is saving off the old table chains, starting a fresh table, computing the new hash value from the old items (which are still valid nodes), and then **moving** those nodes to their new chain in the new table. The only allocation should be the new table bed of chain pointers.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for replying. How am I supposed to copy the old parameters to the new "fresh table" without inserting tho? Please explain it a bit more "easily" as I'm a 3rd Semester CS undergraduate.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with using `insert()` for rehashing, but you will be making new nodes, which is wasteful. You forget to free the old nodes, though, so you really should have a separate function for inserting a node rather than a value.

Comment: @ThomasMailund Ok, so if I add `free((*H)->list_arr[i]);` into the while loop it should be fine, right?

Comment: @DaveHlave You cannot just free the first element in a bin. There might be more than one there. You will have to run through all the nodes in a bin and free them.

Comment: @ThomasMailund Aaaah true! So it's better (like u said in ur answer) to "connect" them in the new table rather than delete the old ones (which is inefficient) and then allocate new nodes (also inefficient) for the new table and assign the same values, did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @DaveHlave yes, moving them will be easier

Answer (score 0):

OK! After thinking about it for a while, I realized I created a `struct list_node` pointer variable that points to `H->list_arr` which is an array of pointers. That was my mistake. I was supposed to declare it as a `double pointer`.

Here's the modified rehash() function:

```
struct hash_table *rehash(struct hash_table *H)
{
    unsigned int old_size = H->table_size;
    struct list_node **old_entries = H->list_arr;

    H = initialize(2*old_size);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<old_size; i++)
    {
        old_entries[i] = old_entries[i]->next;
        while(old_entries[i]!=NULL)
        {
            insert(H,old_entries[i]->key,old_entries[i]->value);
            old_entries[i] = old_entries[i]->next;
        }
    }

    free(old_entries);

    return H;
}
```

with this code, you will have to return the address of the new `hash_table` to the pointer pointing to the old `hash_table` --> [`H = rehash(H)`] since passing the pointer H as a parameter will only change it locally. Therefore, I tried a second version (because I'm too lazy;) and inattentive and might forget to reassign it) where I don't have to return anything, I want to change it simply by calling the function and my pointer points to the new `hash_table` automatically -> [`rehash(&H)`], here's the other "lazy" alternative:

```
void
rehash(struct hash_table **H)
{
    unsigned int old_size = (*H)->table_size;
    struct list_node **old_entries = (*H)->list_arr;

    *H = initialize(2*old_size);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<old_size; i++)
    {
        old_entries[i] = old_entries[i]->next;
        while(old_entries[i]!=NULL)
        {
            insert(*H,old_entries[i]->key,old_entries[i]->value);
            old_entries[i] = old_entries[i]->next;
        }
    }

    free(old_entries);

    
}
```

If I'm doing something that's inefficient (in terms of space and time), please let me know, as I am only in Bachelor's 3rd semester of CS and we have only started DSA this semester.

Comment: You're probably going to find [this example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5550dd303a76e7d) interesting, adapted from your original post. Above all, note the reuse of the old nodes in the rehash algorithm I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are doing by putting dummy elements at the beginning of each bin is a good idea, but you don't need to allocate such dummies with `malloc()`. You can just make the bin array an array of nodes instead of pointers to nodes. Then you have allocated the dummies when you have allocated the array. So you could define your hash table as

```c
struct hash_table
{
    int table_size;
    struct list_node *list_arr;
};
```

(instead of using `struct list_node **list_arr`).

When you loop through the bins in the initialisation, you have to set the bins' `next` pointer to NULL, but not allocate them.

```c
struct hash_table
*initialize(unsigned int table_size)
{
    struct hash_table *H = malloc(sizeof(*H));
    H->list_arr = malloc(sizeof(*H->list_arr)*table_size);
    H->table_size = table_size;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<table_size; i++)
    {
        // no malloc here!
        H->list_arr[i].next = NULL;
    }

    return H;
}
```

Anyway, that is not pertinent to the rehashing, just a suggestion. But because you have the dummy elements as bins, you can refactor your code (that is the reason I think the dummies are such a good idea). You can get the bin from the table and work from there, without worrying about the table itself after that. You can get the relevant bin for a key with

```c
struct list_node *get_bin(struct hash_table *H, const char *key)
{
    unsigned int index = hash(key, H->table_size);
    return &H->list_arr[index];
}
```

and you can find the node in a bin with

```c
struct list_node *find_node(struct list_node *bin, const char *key)
{
    for (struct list_node *current = bin->next;
         current;
         current = current->next) {
        if(strcmp(current->key,key)==0) return current;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and, for example, simplify insertion to

```c
void prepend_node(struct list_node *node, struct list_node *bin)
{
  node->next = bin->next;
  bin->next = node;
}

void insert(struct hash_table *H, const char *key, const char *value)
{
  struct list_node *bin = get_bin(H, key);
  struct list_node *node = find_node(bin, key);
  if (node) {
    // update node
    free(node->value);
    node->value = malloc(strlen(value)+1);
    strcpy(node->value,value);
  } else {
    // prepend new node
    prepend_node(new_node(key, value), bin);
  }
}
```

where the `new_node()` function looks like

```c
struct list_node *new_node(const char *key, const char *value)
{
  struct list_node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
  if (!node) abort(); // add some error handling here
  node->key = malloc(strlen(key)+1);
  if (!node->key) abort(); // add some error handling here
  strcpy(node->key,key);
  node->value = malloc(strlen(value)+1);
  if (!node->value) abort(); // add some error handling here
  strcpy(node->value,value);
  return node;
}
```

Because the bins are embedded in the array, you can safely assume in all the functions that they aren't `NULL`, which can save you from testing some special cases.

It is not shorter code, because I split it into several functions, but in my opinion, it is more readable when each function does one simple thing. Here, getting the bin, finding the key in a bin, creating a node, pretending to a bin, etc. With "raw" `malloc()` and `strcpy()` and such, scattered through the code, it is harder to track that everything works correctly. The total lines of code grew, but each function is shorter and simpler. And you can get away with it, because you can work on bins as lists, without accessing the hash table array, exactly because all bins have a dummy head element.

You can now rewrite `rehash()` to just prepend to bins. You know that all the keys in the old bins are unique, so you don't need to check anything. You just put each node at the front of its new bin:

```c
struct hash_table *rehash(struct hash_table *H)
{
    unsigned int old_size = H->table_size;
    struct list_node *old_entries = H->list_arr;
    free(H); // You forgot to free this one!
    H = initialize(2*old_size);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<old_size; i++)
    {
        struct list_node *old_bin = &old_entries[i];
        for (struct list_node *node = old_bin->next;
             node; node = node->next) {
          // just prepend to new bin; the key should be unique
          prepend_node(node, get_bin(H, node->key));
        }
    }
    free(old_entries);

    return H;
}
```

I added a `free(H)` because you forgot to free memory for `H`, but it would be more efficient to update `H` without creating a new table. You can separate initialisation and allocation. But you do not gain terribly much as initialising the bins is the time-consuming part.

Speaking of freeing, though. Remember to write a function for freeing a hash table (that remembers to free the bins, including all the nodes). Don't use it with rehashing, of course, if you free `H` before you update it--you need to keep the nodes around--but you do want such a function.

Comment: That is genius. Thank you! Btw, I only dereference variables as a parameter for `sizeof()` thanks to your tip from my previous post, it's so much more safe.